# Access Grand Total not correct

Tags: vba, ms-access, formula

I have a Access Report that I have been working on that uses a formula in the Details to add up rows. Then I am wanting to Grand Total that Total column. The Total on the row is working perfectly, however the Grand Total is not adding everything up correctly.

**Formula Total for each Row**

```
=IIf([Pkg] Like "*Large Drum*",[SQtyProd]*[DrmChrg],[SQtyPD]*[PltChrg])+[XPallet]+[OrderChg]+[Label]+[Wrap]+[Labor]+[Rush]
```

**Grand Total Formula in Footer**

```
=Sum(IIf([Pkg] Like "*Large Drum*",[SQtyProd]*[DrmChrg],[SQtyPD]*[PltChrg])+[XPallet]+[OrderChg]+[Label]+[Wrap]+[Labor]+[Rush])
```

**SQL from Report**

```
SELECT DISTINCT tblShipping.SDate, tblShipping.shpOrder, tblShipping.shpSKU, tblShipping.shpSKU, tblShipping.shpLot, tblShipping.shpQtyProd, tblShipping.shpQtyPD, tblShipping.shpXPallet, tblShipping.shpOrderChg, tblShipping.shpLabel, tblShipping.shpLabel1, tblShipping.shpWrap, tblShipping.shpBand, tblShipping.shpLabor, tblShipping.shpLabor1, tblShipping.shpRush, tblPricing.*, tblProduct.*, tblInvoice.*
FROM tblPricing, tblInvoice, tblProduct INNER JOIN tblShipping ON tblProduct.SKU = tblShipping.[shpSKU]
WHERE (((tblShipping.SDate) Between [Forms]![frmInvoice]![ctrSDate] And [Forms]![frmInvoice]![ctrEDate]));
```

Comment: Your Grand Total has an extra field in the calculation -- tblInvoice.UPS

Comment: If I take that out it still doesn't work. What else could be wrong?

Comment: could you be a little more specific about the totals not being correct? Is the grand total too much, too little? Is the Grand Total just supposed to sum the prior row totals?

Comment: The Grand Total is only summing the `(IIf([Pkg] Like "*Large Drum*",[SQtyProd]*[DrmChrg],[SQtyPD]*[PltChrg])`.  It is not including `+[XPallet]+[OrderChg]+[Label]+[Wrap]+[Labor]+[Rush]` So therefore the total is too small. The Total column in the details adds up the row totals across and the Grand Total just needs to sum the Total column at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by creating a total for each column in the footer and then adding those together in the grand total field. Finally I hid those labels so they wouldn't be seen.

Answer (score 0):

Your current formula includes a right paren that may be causing your problem. What you currently have is:

```
=Sum(IIf([Pkg] Like "*Large Drum*",[SQtyProd]*[DrmChrg],[SQtyPD]*[PltChrg])+[XPallet]+[OrderChg]+[Label]+[Wrap]+[Labor]+[Rush])
```

I suggest trying the following. Although it should produce the same result as what you have, yours is not working (also, to someone picking up later, it seems clearer what the intent is):

```
=Sum(IIf([Pkg] Like "*Large Drum*",([SQtyProd]*[DrmChrg]+[XPallet]+[OrderChg]+[Label]+[Wrap]+[Labor]+[Rush]),([SQtyPD]*[PltChrg]+[XPallet]+[OrderChg]+[Label]+[Wrap]+[Labor]+[Rush])))
```

**SQL from Report**

```
SELECT DISTINCT tblShipping.SDate, tblShipping.shpOrder, tblShipping.shpSKU, tblShipping.shpSKU, tblShipping.shpLot, tblShipping.shpQtyProd, tblShipping.shpQtyPD, tblShipping.shpXPallet, tblShipping.shpOrderChg, tblShipping.shpLabel, tblShipping.shpLabel1, tblShipping.shpWrap, tblShipping.shpBand, tblShipping.shpLabor, tblShipping.shpLabor1, tblShipping.shpRush, tblPricing.*, tblProduct.*, tblInvoice.*
FROM tblPricing, tblInvoice, tblProduct INNER JOIN tblShipping ON tblProduct.SKU = tblShipping.[shpSKU]
WHERE (((tblShipping.SDate) Between [Forms]![frmInvoice]![ctrSDate] And [Forms]![frmInvoice]![ctrEDate]));
```

Comment: It still doesn't total correctly... any other ideas?

Comment: I created a table with all those fields, populated 10 records, set values of fields as 1,2,3,4,... and I get 47 or 57 as a total depending on matching 'Large Drum'. My subtotals are correct and report total is correct. Can you update your question by showing the SQL that is the record source for the report? Also, if you have not done so, copy the subtotal control and paste into the report footer as a validation check.

Comment: OK, since the variables you use in your 'SUM' don't exist in your tables. where defined/what are things like 'PKG' and 'SQtyProd', etc.?

Comment: Pkg / PltChrg / DrmChrg is found under the **tblProduct** table and SQtyProd / SQtyPD is found under the **tblShipping** table

Comment: Would it help if I could send you a link to the actual database?

Comment: That would make it very simple.